# wxWidgets app on windows 10 Pro has linker errors

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a wxWidget app that builds fine on MacOS and Linux. On Windows 10 Pro, I used MSVC to create an empty project, added all required header and library paths. The code builds fine, but when it comes to linking, it links only with wxbase32u.lib. This appears to be insufficient because it throws 918 errors. According to the documentation MSVC's #pragma comment(lib) is supposed to automatically pick up all the required libraries, but it's not doing that. Any pointers on how to fix this issue?

TIA

```
Severity
Code
Description
Project
File
Line
Suppression State
Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: static class wxString __cdecl wxString::FromAscii(char const *)" (?FromAscii@wxString@@SA?AV1@PEBD@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "private: static struct wxString::SubstrBufFromType<class wxScopedCharTypeBuffer<wchar_t> > __cdecl wxString::ConvertStr(char const *,unsigned __int64,class wxMBConv const &)" (?ConvertStr@wxString@@CA?AU?$SubstrBufFromType@V?$wxScopedCharTypeBuffer@_W@@@1@PEBD_KAEBVwxMBConv@@@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl wxEvent::wxEvent(int,int)" (??0wxEvent@@QEAA@HH@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl wxEvent::wxEvent(class wxEvent const &)" (??0wxEvent@@IEAA@AEBV0@@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl wxNodeBase::~wxNodeBase(void)" (??1wxNodeBase@@UEAA@XZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl wxNodeBase::wxNodeBase(class wxListBase *,class wxNodeBase *,class wxNodeBase *,void *,class wxListKey const &)" (??0wxNodeBase@@QEAA@PEAVwxListBase@@PEAV0@1PEAXAEBVwxListKey@@@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@YAXPEBDH000@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl wxOnAssert(char const *,int,char const *,char const *,wchar_t const *)" (?wxOnAssert@@YAXPEBDH00PEB_W@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxNotebookNameStr" (?wxNotebookNameStr@@3QBDB)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "protected: void __cdecl wxArrayString::Init(bool)" (?Init@wxArrayString@@IEAAX_N@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl wxArrayString::~wxArrayString(void)" (??1wxArrayString@@QEAA@XZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: class wxArrayString & __cdecl wxArrayString::operator=(class wxArrayString const &)" (??4wxArrayString@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class wxEventHashTable & __cdecl wxGrid::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (?GetEventHashTable@wxGrid@@MEBAAEAVwxEventHashTable@@XZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct wxEventTable const * __cdecl wxGrid::GetEventTable(void)const " (?GetEventTable@wxGrid@@MEBAPEBUwxEventTable@@XZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class wxClassInfo * __cdecl wxGrid::GetClassInfo(void)const " (?GetClassInfo@wxGrid@@UEBAPEAVwxClassInfo@@XZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "private: virtual class wxSize __cdecl wxGrid::GetSizeAvailableForScrollTarget(class wxSize const &)" (?GetSizeAvailableForScrollTarget@wxGrid@@EEAA?AVwxSize@@AEBV2@@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "protected: void __cdecl wxGrid::Init(void)" (?Init@wxGrid@@IEAAXXZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl wxGrid::DoEnable(bool)" (?DoEnable@wxGrid@@MEAAX_N@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class wxSize __cdecl wxGrid::DoGetBestSize(void)const " (?DoGetBestSize@wxGrid@@MEBA?AVwxSize@@XZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl wxGrid::SetFocus(void)" (?SetFocus@wxGrid@@UEAAXXZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl wxGrid::Fit(void)" (?Fit@wxGrid@@UEAAXXZ)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl wxGrid::SetDropTarget(class wxDropTarget *)" (?SetDropTarget@wxGrid@@UEAAXPEAVwxDropTarget@@@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1

Error
LNK2001
unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class wxGridCellRenderer * __cdecl wxGrid::GetDefaultRendererForType(class wxString const &)const " (?GetDefaultRendererForType@wxGrid@@UEBAPEAVwxGridCellRenderer@@AEBVwxString@@@Z)
visor_wx_win
C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\dlg_display_logs.obj
1
```

Here is the build output, snipped because it overflows SO body size limit

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: visor_wx_win, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.Cpp.Analysis.props(24,5): warning MSB4211: The property "MsvcAnalysisPluginPath" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Extensions.props (33,5)".
1>dlg_display_logs.cpp
1>dlg_get_settings.cpp
1>dlg_show_fw_list.cpp
1>network_thread.cpp
1>sftp_thread.cpp
1>utils.cpp
1>visor.cpp
1>visor_frame.cpp
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(701,19): warning C4101: 'buf': unreferenced local variable
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(1671,10): warning C4101: 'version': unreferenced local variable
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(2132,19): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(2491,9): warning C4101: 'len': unreferenced local variable
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(2485,11): warning C4101: 'asciiBuf': unreferenced local variable
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(2677,9): warning C4101: 'devNameLength': unreferenced local variable
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(2676,9): warning C4101: 'strLength': unreferenced local variable
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\server\visor_frame.cpp(2755,13): warning C4101: 'devNameLength': unreferenced local variable
1>dlg_display_logs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class wxString __cdecl wxString::FromAscii(char const *)" (?FromAscii@wxString@@SA?AV1@PEBD@Z)
1>dlg_display_logs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct wxString::SubstrBufFromType<class wxScopedCharTypeBuffer<wchar_t> > __cdecl wxString::ConvertStr(char const *,unsigned __int64,class wxMBConv const &)" (?ConvertStr@wxString@@CA?AU?$SubstrBufFromType@V?$wxScopedCharTypeBuffer@_W@@@1@PEBD_KAEBVwxMBConv@@@Z)
1>dlg_display_logs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl wxEvent::wxEvent(int,int)" (??0wxEvent@@QEAA@HH@Z)
1>dlg_display_logs.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl wxEvent::wxEvent(class wxEvent const &)" (??0wxEvent@@IEAA@AEBV0@@Z)

----- snip ----

1>visor_frame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl wxSocketBase::Notify(bool)" (?Notify@wxSocketBase@@QEAAX_N@Z)
1>visor_frame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl wxSocketBase::SetNotify(int)" (?SetNotify@wxSocketBase@@QEAAXH@Z)
1>visor_frame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl wxSocketBase::SetEventHandler(class wxEvtHandler &,int)" (?SetEventHandler@wxSocketBase@@QEAAXAEAVwxEvtHandler@@H@Z)
1>visor_frame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl wxSocketBase::SetFlags(int)" (?SetFlags@wxSocketBase@@QEAAXH@Z)
1>visor_frame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl wxMutex::wxMutex(enum wxMutexType)" (??0wxMutex@@QEAA@W4wxMutexType@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\LK\projects\visor_wxwidgets\visor_wx_win\x64\Release\visor_wx_win.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 917 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "visor_wx_win.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 4:39 PM and took 20.824 seconds ==========
```

This is the .sln file

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.5.33627.172
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "visor_wx_win", "visor_wx_win.vcxproj", "{CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}"
EndProject
Global
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
                Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
                Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
                DLL Debug|x64 = DLL Debug|x64
                DLL Debug|x86 = DLL Debug|x86
                DLL Release|x64 = DLL Release|x64
                DLL Release|x86 = DLL Release|x86
                Release|x64 = Release|x64
                Release|x86 = Release|x86
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.DLL Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
                {CDEB4905-D7C0-41E3-A0A3-5B9BF6FE26A4}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
                HideSolutionNode = FALSE
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
                SolutionGuid = {CABF3B0F-E922-4EDD-B298-55C81861BE4D}
        EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

This is the .vcxproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <ProjectGuid>{cdeb4905-d7c0-41e3-a0a3-5b9bf6fe26a4}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>visorwxwin</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS;__WXMSW__;_UNICODE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(OPEN_SSL)\include;$(LIBSSH2)\include;$(WXWIN)\include;$(WXWIN)\include\msvc;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_x64_lib</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\dlg_display_logs.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\dlg_get_settings.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\dlg_show_fw_list.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\network_thread.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\sftp_thread.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\utils.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\visor.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\visor_frame.cpp">
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">..\common;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="..\common\buffer_io.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\common\common.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\dlg_display_logs.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\dlg_get_settings.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\dlg_show_fw_list.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\embedded_image_data.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\network_thread.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\server_common.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\sftp_thread.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\utils.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\visor.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\visor_frame.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

This is the .vcxproj.filters

```
╗┐<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Filter Include="Source Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{4FC737F1-C7A5-4376-A066-2A32D752A2FF}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>cpp;c;cc;cxx;c++;cppm;ixx;def;odl;idl;hpj;bat;asm;asmx</Extensions>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Header Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{93995380-89BD-4b04-88EB-625FBE52EBFB}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>h;hh;hpp;hxx;h++;hm;inl;inc;ipp;xsd</Extensions>
    </Filter>
    <Filter Include="Resource Files">
      <UniqueIdentifier>{67DA6AB6-F800-4c08-8B7A-83BB121AAD01}</UniqueIdentifier>
      <Extensions>rc;ico;cur;bmp;dlg;rc2;rct;bin;rgs;gif;jpg;jpeg;jpe;resx;tiff;tif;png;wav;mfcribbon-ms</Extensions>
    </Filter>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\dlg_display_logs.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\dlg_get_settings.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\dlg_show_fw_list.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\network_thread.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\sftp_thread.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\utils.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\visor.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
    <ClCompile Include="..\server\visor_frame.cpp">
      <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\dlg_display_logs.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\dlg_get_settings.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\dlg_show_fw_list.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\embedded_image_data.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\network_thread.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\server_common.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\sftp_thread.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\utils.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\visor.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\server\visor_frame.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\common\buffer_io.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="..\common\common.h">
      <Filter>Header Files</Filter>
    </ClInclude>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And this is the .users file

```
∩╗┐<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup />
</Project>
```

Comment: _"The code builds fine"_ - Consider that a build necessarily includes linking, so I think what you meant was that the front-end compiler runs fine, but the linking phase of the build fails - so no: _the code does not build fine_.

Comment: Show us your MSBuild project file and the full linker command-line - it will appear in VS's Output window.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and you are right, the code does not build fine, my bad! I have updated the post with the MSBuild project files.

Comment: @VogiWannabe, look at the place where wxbase library is - you will see the wbase_net library. You need to add this to the list.

Comment: I added wxbase_net library but that did not help. I then added all the .lib files from wxwidget and that too did not help. I still get 918 errors. This is very weird!

Comment: @YogiWannabe, did you build the library? Do you actually have those files anywhere? Finally - can you build and run minimal sample?

Answer (score 0):

You're not linking with the "core" wxWidgets library (`wxmsw32u_core.lib`), so it's not surprising that you get link errors. You do need to link with it, which you can do by:

1. Simply using `wxwidgets.props` as [described in the documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/plat_msw_install.html#msw_build_apps) -- recommended.
2. Setting up include paths so that `include/msvc` directory is there and rely on autolinking.
3. Just link with the library above (and any other ones you use) explicitly.

But it is rather surprising that you expect things to work without doing any of the above.

Comment: (s)he is probably not a native Windows developer and on *nix/Mac just uses `wx-config`.